# Setting exposure lock when flash is on

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to set an exposure lock on my Galaxy S7 edge (Camera2 FULL) with: 
`mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true);`
 However, this is not working while the flash is enabled with: 
`mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);` 
When the flash is disabled, the exposure does lock.

On my other devices (that are Camera2 LIMITED ), this works perfectly fine. (even with flash)

Is there something I'm not seeing here or is it a bug? Can't find much information about this.

Thanks !

Comment: Was there a workaround that you discovered, or some sort of state condition for the camera to make it functional?